# Grabbing data on GET and sending serialized JSON to model vs API call

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Which one is a better practice and better performance-wise, or is there a different option to consider? A lot of the apps at my company utilize kendo UI, and to grab the data, they do an API call on the client-side. Depending on how large the information is (sometimes 800-1k+ indexes), it can take a couple of seconds to retrieve.

I've also experimented with grabbing this data on the server-side, serializing it, then sending it to the model and adding a hidden HTML element. The client JS can then parse the data and the kendo elements initialize instantly.

I haven't experienced any slow down on page load, and data loads instantly, so I'm assuming this may be a better option instead of relying on the client. As for the security differences and if other performant options exist, I am not sure of.

Comment: What kind of information are you fetching? What are indexes? I think you should reconsider your application UI. Maybe add some paging to the items shown?

Comment: Paging is enabled, but the slow speed is coming from the server communicating with the client and the client handling the data load. The amount of data being returned is putting stress on the clientside. By indexes I'm referring to the indexes returned in a JSON object. The JSON object information I'm returning is roughly 15 elements per index, all strings/int/dates.